# why cannot I type password in putty?

Tags: password, putty, console

When I open a session in putty to connect to the server, the console asks:

`login as:` so I type root or another username

then the console ask `username@ip.ip.ip.ip's password:` From here I can't type anything except Entry which brings me to Access denied, all the other keys don't output anything in the console.

Comment: What do you mean? Of course the password isn't shown on the console.

Comment: ok, so I typed the password cautiously, and it worked. I feel so stupid. Thank you very much. It seems that this was a newbie question from the outerspace. I was expecting the console to react in anyway, like with **.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminal isn't echoing the password or stars in place of the password. Try ignoring what you see and just enter the password. It is very common in unix to turn off echoing when entering passwords.